# Combining two lists into dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm having issues trying to combine two lists that I have, Username and Account into a dictionary(username being the key and account being the value). My issue is I want any value with the same key to be added together(i.e the Brandon would only show up once with a value of 115.5). I would also like to skip the key/value pair for any blank or non-number values. Any help would be appreciated.

```
username = ['Brandon', 'Patrick', 'Brandon', 'Jack', '', 'Sarah', 'Jack', 'Brandon', 'James', 'James', 'Sarah', '', 'Brandon']
account = ['5', '18.9', 'xyz', '', '', '825', '45', '10', '3.25', '125.62', '2.43', '', '100.5']
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Could you edit your question to show what you have tried and what didn’t work? See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to some details. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can zip together corresponding elements. Skip invalid values by catching errors on conversion to float, and use the falsiness of empty strings to skip empty keys

```py
names = {}

for k, v in zip(username, account):
    # check for empty keys
    if not k:
        continue

    # an error on float conversion is due to a non
    # numeric string (float or int)
    try:
        v = float(v)
    except:
        continue
    
    # if the key is not in names, then .get will return
    # 0, otherwise the last value set
    names[k] = names.get(k, 0) + v

names
{'Brandon': 115.5, 'Patrick': 18.9, 'Sarah': 827.43, 'Jack': 45.0, 'James': 128.87}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

The more advanced things you may want to look up are: defaultdict and zip

```
from collections import defaultdict

username = ['Brandon', 'Patrick', 'Brandon', 'Jack', '', 'Sarah', 'Jack', 'Brandon', 'James', 'James', 'Sarah', '', 'Brandon']
account = ['5', '18.9', 'xyz', '', '', '825', '45', '10', '3.25', '125.62', '2.43', '', '100.5']

result = defaultdict(list)
for u, a in zip(username, account):
    if a != '':
        result[u].append(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip`. `all` with check the conditions if `not ''` and `value is not numeric`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(float)
for i in zip(username, account):
    if all([*i, i[1].replace('.','').isdigit()]):
        d[i[0]] += float(i[1])
```

```
{'Brandon': 115.5,
             'Patrick': 18.9,
             'Sarah': 827.43,
             'Jack': 45.0,
             'James': 128.87}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def isfloat(value):
  try:
    float(value)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    return False

username = ['Brandon', 'Patrick', 'Brandon', 'Jack', '', 'Sarah', 'Jack', 'Brandon', 'James', 'James', 'Sarah', '', 'Brandon']
account = ['5', '18.9', 'xyz', '', '', '825', '45', '10', '3.25', '125.62', '2.43', '', '100.5']

result = {}
for u, a in zip(username, account):
    if isfloat(a):
        if u not in result.keys():
            result[u] = float(a)
        else:
            result[u] += float(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help, try part will automatically skip any non-digit values

```
username = ['Brandon', 'Patrick', 'Brandon', 'Jack', '', 'Sarah', 'Jack', 'Brandon', 'James', 'James', 'Sarah', '', 'Brandon']
account = ['5', '18.9', 'xyz', '', '', '825', '45', '10', '3.25', '125.62', '2.43', '', '100.5']

new_dict = {}
for key, value in zip(username, account):
    try:
        new_dict[key]=new_dict.get(key, 0.0) + float(value)
    except:
        pass

print(new_dict)
```